# Problem accessing objects and includes outside functions from within function

Tags: plugins, wordpress

I am currently building a Wordpress plugin for a customer and I am experiencing some issues with accessing variables and objects that are created outside the function from within the function. For instance, this is my code:

```
// Include files:
require_once('classes/panel.inc.php');
$panel = new AdminPanel();

// Actions & Options:
add_action('admin_menu', 'configurePages');

// Configure pages:
function configurePages(){

    // Boats:
    add_menu_page(__('Båtar','admin-main'), __('Båtar','boats'), 'manage_options', 'boats', array($panel, 'displayBoatManager'));
    add_submenu_page('boats', __('Sök båtar','search-boats'), __('Sök objekt','search-boats'), 'manage_options', 'search-boats', array($panel, 'displayBoatSearch'));
    add_submenu_page('boats', __('Hantera utrustning','manage-equipment'), __('Hantera utrustning','manage-equipment'), 'manage_options', 'manage-equipment', array($panel, 'displayEquipmentManager'));

    // Customers:
    add_menu_page(__('Kunder','admin-main'), __('Kunder','boats'), 'manage_options', 'customers', array($panel, 'displayCustomerManager'));
    add_submenu_page('customers', __('Sök kunder','search-customers'), __('Sök kunder','search-customers'), 'manage_options', 'search-customers', array($panel, 'displayCustomerSearch'));
}
```

As you can see I already created a panel object, and if I dump the content before the function I get a correct output. Though, all the pages complain that panel is not a valid variable nor an object. What could be causing this?

I can solve it by simple adding:

```
require_once('classes/panel.inc.php');
$panel = new AdminPanel();
```

Inside the configurePages function. But I should not have to do this.
I have the same problem with includes, they simple wont get recognized inside the functions. I would be very happy if someone could share some insight in this issue and possible how to solve it.

Thanks in advance! //
Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `$panel` from within the function, since your function is looking for a variable `$panel` in it's local scope, while it has actually been defined in the global scope.

One way to make the variable available within the function is

```
function configurePages() {
  global $panel;
  …
}
```

More on the scope of variables can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thanks, this works great for the variables, but I'm not sure how I could apply this to any kind of function like "require_once" or "include_once". I want to have my configuration in another file but still be able to reach it from all functions. Do you happen to know how to do this?

Comment: Hard to tell without the file content, but I would assume that you're again trying to access some configuration variables in your function which have been defined in those included files withiin the global scope. If that's the case, you'll have to call `global` for those variables as well: `global $panel, $config, ...;` while `$config` has been defined in an include.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it seems it does not help. Any variables that have been created inside that file seems to be out of reach. I was hoping to get this to work, but I guess I will just put it all in one file then.

Comment: I managed to get the includes working, but I had to set the variables as global before setting their content in the config file and then setting them as includes again within the function that I needed to utilize them in. Thanks for all the help, problem solved!